# Weak decays classification

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

Sir,
  We often read about Cabibbo Favourite, Singly Cabibbo Suppressed and Doubly Cabibbo Suppressed decays. I have two questions:

1. I understand that the suppressed decays are rarer but why are there two of them one singly and one doubly?
2. Also if we consider the CKM matrix and its elements $V_{ij}$ is it correct to say that:

   Cabibbo-Favorite (CF) decays involve quark mixing described by $V_{ij}$ elements on the diagonal of $V_{\mathrm{CKM}}$. CF decays do not present any direct CP violation.

   Doubly-Cabibbo-Suppressed (DCS) decays, like ${D^0\to K^+\pi^-}$, involve quark mixing described by $V_{ij}$ elements on the $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ positions in the $V_{\mathrm{CKM}}$ matrix. DCS decays do not present any CP violation and are more exotic.

   Finally Singly-Cabibbo-Suppressed (SCS) decays, like $D^0\to K^+K^-\pi^+\pi^-$, involve quark mixing described by $V_{ij}$ elements on the $(2,3)$, $(3,2)$, $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ positions in the $V_{\mathrm{CKM}}$ matrix. SCS decays present source of direct CP violation.